# SimPy - infinite run time bug

Tags: python, simpy, event-simulation

I have observed some "odd" behaviour with SimPy event scheduling.

When a nan value, is used as the delay in the `env.timeout` method, it **sometimes**, overwrites the `until = XXX` parameter inside the `env.run` method.

I have outlined a minimal example, to show the inconsistent behaviour of this. If you run all 3 test cases, you will see test 2 runs forever.

Looking through the source code, it appears to be some interaction between, timeout and scheduling, but have not got further than this.

**Q: Could someone help me understand, why the `until` parameter is overwritten when, in a specific order, null values are entered in the `timout` method?**

```
import simpy
import numpy as np
# Set up a minimal SimPy process
def func1(env, time, name):
    while True:
        print(f'process: {name}, delayed for {time},  time:', env.now)
        # print(env._queue)
        # print('================')
        yield env.timeout(time)

def test_one():
    """Stops after 20 days - Normal process at the start"""
    env = simpy.Environment() 
    env.process(func1(env = env, time = 2, name = '3'))
    env.process(func1(env = env, time = np.nan, name = '2'))
    env.process(func1(env = env, time = np.nan, name = '1'))
    env.process(func1(env = env, time = np.nan, name = '3'))
    env.run(until = 20)
    
def test_two():
    """Runs forever - Normal process at the end"""
    env = simpy.Environment() 
    env.process(func1(env = env, time = np.nan, name = '2'))
    env.process(func1(env = env, time = np.nan, name = '1'))
    env.process(func1(env = env, time = np.nan, name = '3'))
    env.process(func1(env = env, time = 2, name = '3'))
    env.run(until = 20)
    
def test_three():
    """Stops after 20 days - Normal process in 2nd position"""
    env = simpy.Environment() 
    env.process(func1(env = env, time = np.nan, name = '2'))
    env.process(func1(env = env, time = 2, name = '3'))
    env.process(func1(env = env, time = np.nan, name = '1'))
    env.process(func1(env = env, time = np.nan, name = '3'))
    env.run(until = 20)
```